# Problems with forceDoubleSided setting

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to activate the profile setting forceDoubleSided in order to display properly a model derivated from a Revit project that has mirrored external references.

Using the latest version of the Forge Viewer, I set the profile settings in the config parameter when I call `new GuiViewer3D(container, config)` and, while the model is loading, the materials property "side" = 2 (THREE.DoubleSide) and it looks good.

The problem is when the model has loaded, or after have used the cutting plane extension, because the materials "side" is then reset to 0 (THREE.FrontSide) so the model stops looking correctly.

As a workaround, in the GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT and CUTPLANES_CHANGE_EVENT events I am executing `_viewer.impl.setDoubleSided(true, _viewer.model)` every time.

It seems like a bug in the viewer... is there a better approach to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That does sound like a bug. Let me notify the engineering team, and thanks for reporting it! For now, please continue manually overriding the "sidedness" as needed.

Comment: Besides "geometry loaded" and "cut planes", do you think of other cases I should be aware of?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are other areas in the code where the option could be cleared or overridden. I've asked the engineering team and will report here once I have more info.