# Mirrored model has its materials flipped inside out when viewed in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

### Description

- Mirrored model has its materials flipped inside out when viewed in Autodesk Forge Viewer.
- Adding a section plane reverts the mirrored model back to what it should look like.
- We are using this [sample viewer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/nodejs) from Autodesk.
- This weird behavior does not occur when looking at the model in BIM 360 Docs.

We've included screenshots and steps to reproduce this [here](https://github.com/peelstnac/Autodesk-Forge-Viewer-Mirrored-Model-Issue).

EDIT: while writing this post, we came across [Problems with forceDoubleSided setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559195/problems-with-forcedoublesided-setting). Has this been fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loading the `'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension'` might fix the problem.
See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-viewer-vs-forge-viewer